# как вытащить список городов из яндекса (работа) python

Tags: html, python, json, веб-программирование, парсер

Задача: получить количество вакансий по определенным городам

---

rabota.yandex.ru/search?rid=225
ссылка на страницу "Россия", rid (region id) = 225
В идеале, нужно узнать эти rid для каждого города и в цикле меняя url собирать данные, но rid вытащить не получается
пробовал с помощью selenium вписывать название городов в графу и получать данные, но допустим нельзя выбрать город "Самара" есть только "Самара, Самарская область" как вариант для поиска в яндексе, а когда вписываешь это с помощью send_keys запрос не проходит

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

table=pd.read_html('http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/685243')
table=table[1]
town_list=table[2]
town_list=town_list[1:len(town_list)]
data = pd.DataFrame(index=range((len(town_list),3)),columns=['city',             'url','volume'])
data['url'].apply(str)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://rabota.yandex.ru/search?rid=225')
form = \
browser.find_element_by_name('rid')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30, ignored_exceptions=1)

for i in range(0,len(town_list)):
    url0 = browser.current_url
    form.clear()
    form.send_keys(town_list.iat[i])
    #print (town_list.iat[i])
    time.sleep(2)
    form.submit()
    wait.until(lambda browser: browser.current_url != url0)
    data.iloc[i,1] = browser.current_url
    #print ( browser.current_url)
```

был план такой, чтобы вытащить так ссылки на страницы с вакансиями по нужным городам а потом вытащить из каждой страницы уже число вакансий

```
int(re.split(' ', browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'вакансий')]").text)[0])
```

Если посмотреть в коде страницы в графе network (так называется в хроме), то в момент ввода города в поисковую строку появляется запрос "rabota.yandex.ru/gate/suggest/regions"
где лежит response, со словариком, в котором есть как раз rid городов
Каааак получиииить его)) ведь получив список городов, я бы просто прошелся в цикле, собрав все что мне нужно)) Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import requests

r = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/yaca/geo.c2n')
r.raise_for_status()
lines = r.content.decode(r.apparent_encoding).splitlines()
regions = dict(line.split('\t') for line in lines)
```

#### Результат

```
{'0': 'Регионы',
 '1': 'Москва и область',
 '10': 'Орел',
 '100': 'Франкфурт-на-Майне',
 '10002': 'Северная Америка',
 ...,
 '98': 'Кельн',
 '983': 'Турция',
 '99': 'Мюнхен',
 '994': 'Индия',
 '995': 'Таиланд'}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Есть еще, в таком случае, вопрос к Вам:
мне нужно выбрать из этого словарика ключи, которые соответствуют городам с населением больше 100 тысяч
(список городов нашел здесь: dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/685243)
как сопоставить их, если кое-где различаются названия

Comment: @AlexanderMazitov: если у вас новый вопрос, то задайте его как отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день. Я не уверен, что правильно понял Ваш вопрос. Но список с rid городов (или "регионов") доступен по этой ссылке:
https://yandex.ru/yaca/geo.c2n
Ссылку взял тут:
https://tech.yandex.ru/xml/doc/dg/reference/regions-docpage/

Answer (score -2):

Добрый день! У меня тоже был такой опыт. Смотрите, вам нужно в вашем python файле сделать запрос на данные, а именно:

```
import requests

abc = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/yaca/geo.c2n')
menu = abc.c2n()
```

Comment: что такое .c2n() ? нет такого метода